# Beautiful Soup can't get news titles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url ="http://www.basketnews.lt/lygos/59-nacionaline-krepsinio-asociacija/2013/naujienos.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

naujienos = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'title'})

print naujienos
```

Here is important part of HTML:

```
<div class="title">

    <a href="/news-73147-rockets-veikiausiai-pasiliks-mchalea.html"></a>
    <span class="feedbacks"></span>

</div>
```

I get empty list. Where is my mistake?

EDIT:

Thanks it worked. Now I want to print news titles. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
nba = soup.select('div.title > a')

for i in nba:
   print ""+i.string+"\n"
```

I get max 5 titles and error occurs: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: Maybe the tag 'a' should to have the class in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup.findAll('a', {'class':'title'})
```

This says, give me all `a` tags that also have `class="title"`.  That's obviously not what you're trying to do.

I think you want `a` tags that are the *direct descendant* of a tag with `class="title"`.  You can try using a css selector:

```
soup.select('div.title > a')
Out[58]: 
[<a href="/news-73150-blatcheas-garantuoju-kad-laimesime.html">Blatche'as: âGarantuoju, kad laimÄsimeâ</a>,
 <a href="/news-73147-rockets-veikiausiai-pasiliks-mchalea.html">âRocketsâ veikiausiai pasiliks McHaleâÄ
</a>,
# snip lots of other links
]
```

Comment: THanks it worked, but now I have one more problem. I edited my first question

Comment: well, don't do that.  just print `i.string` and you'll see that some of them are `None` (did you want `i.text`?).  Also `print` already adds a newline on the end, I don't know why you're trying to add another.

Comment: Oh, i.text worked but I am getting titles not in utf8(?). In text are that kind of symbols: Å¾ â Å and so on.